# ListBoxItem results unclickable while ProgressBar performs steps

Tags: c#, xaml, click, progress-bar, listboxitem

I have a DataTemplate which describes the Items of a ListBox in XAML. Into each Item I have four things:

1) a progress bar

2) three buttons

I noticed that when the progress bar is advancing, the buttons result to be unclickable, why?

There is my XAML code referring to the abovementioned ListBox:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Name="TransfersList" Margin="30,10,-0.444,34.889" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTx}"
             SelectionChanged="TransfersList_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ProgressBar Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding NChunks}" Name="gasparino_il_carbonaro"
                                 Value="{Binding PbStatus}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"
                                 ToolTip="{Binding TooltipInfo}" />
                    <Button Content="Delete all" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Background="White"
                            Click="DeleteAllTransfersClick" />
                    <Button Content="Stop all" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Background="White"
                            Click="StopAllTransfersClick" />
                    <Button Content="Resume all" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Background="White"
                            Click="ResumeAllTransfersClick" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: I think it's because your main thread is updating the progress bar UI

Comment: I think you are right. What do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0):

It happens in Single threaded application. To use multi threaded concept, show progress  bar using using event & delegates.